# Python Webhook to download and upload files with different extensions

Tags: python, urllib2, webhooks

I'm making a Python Webhook to intercept FormStack data (sent in JSON format) which includes a file attachment url. I need to download the file attachment and the send it as a mail attachment through SendGrid API.

The SendGrid API requires filename and path as arguments to attach the file.
`message.add_attachment('stuff.txt', './stuff.txt')`

I referred to `urllib2` but I can't seem to find out a way to download file with any extension and get its location for uploading it further.

Comment: So you need to download the file and attach it to an email? _What_ do you mean by _uploading it further_?

Comment: Yep you understood it right. I need to attach it to an email. At least for now.

Comment: You might take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22776/3991125) and save the read/downloaded file to a dedicated directory. Then you could use `os.path`'s functions or, since you know the directory/path a priori, even simpler string methods to separete filename and extension if needed and add it to the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete elaborated code that worked for me

```
import tempfile
import sendgrid

url = 'your download url'
file_name = file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
t_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=file_name, dir="/mydir_loc" delete=False) 

# Default directory is '/tmp' but you can explicitly mention a directory also  
# Set Delete to True if you want the file to be deleted after closing

data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
t_file.write(data)

# SendGrid API calls
message.add_attachment(file_name, tf.name)
status, msg = sg.send(message)

t_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Download it to a temporary file, e.g. using `tempfile`.
Key lines (simplified):

```
s = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.txt', delete=False)  # OPT: dir=mytempdir
tf.write(s)
path = tf.name
tf.close()
```